# Filter List of Objects

Tags: c#, list, object, find

I want to store Objects of the class Rezept in the list List RezepteListe. After that I want to  filter that RezepteListe regarding their NameID. But obviously I dont get the Filter() Method run on my RezepteListe.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public List<Rezept> RezepteListe = new List<Rezept>();
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Rezept Kartoffelsalat = new Rezept("Kartoffelsalat");
        textBox1.Text = Kartoffelsalat.NameID;

        RezepteListe.Add(Kartoffelsalat);
        textBox1.Text = RezepteListe.Where(x => x.NameID == "Kartoffelsalat");

        List<String> liste2 = new List<string>();
        liste2.Add("Hallo");
        textBox1.Text= liste2.Find(x => x == "Hallo");
    }
}

public class Rezept
{
    public List<string> Zutat { get; set; }
    public string NameID { get; set; }

    public Rezept(string NameID)
    {
        this.NameID = NameID;
    }

}
```

Comment: `textBox1.Text = RezepteListe.FirstOrDefault(x => x.NameID == "Kartoffelsalat")?.NameID;`?

Comment: textBox1.text is supposed to be a string I guess
The LINQ Where method returns an IEnumerable.
So you try to assing an IEnumerable to a string field.

Comment: but why is that question mark there? is that an if statement, what then returns the object.NameID?

Comment: @Lion that's the null conditional member access operator, it returns `null` if its first argument is `null`, and else behaves like normal `.`